# Create User in dacpac deployed by SqlPackage.exe leads to login failed SqlException

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-project, dacpac, sqlpackage

### Problem

I'm trying to automate SQL deployment including User and Roles. It works when I create the user in Sql Management Studio, but when I deploy dacpack I get SqlException: Login Failed for user 'MyUser'

### Description

1. I have SQL Server 2016 installed on localhost with both Sql Server and Windows authentication enabled.
2. I have Sql Database project in Visual Studio with these files:

   - MyUser.sql [build action=build]

     ```
     CREATE USER [MyUser] WITH Password='$(MyUserPassword)';
     ```
   - RolesMembership.sql [build action=build]

     ```
     ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]
     GO
     ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [MyUser]
     ```
3. I build it and deploy the created dacpac using command line:

   ```
   SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish
                  /SourceFile:"MyDatabase.dacpac" 
                  /Profile:"MyDatabase.publish.xml"
                  /v:MyUserPassword=c2Aaaaaaaaaaaa`
   ```

it works when when I execute this script in sql management studio.  But when I deploy it using SqlPackage it leads to the

> SqlException: Login failed for user 'MyUser'

EDIT:

I've investigated the generated sql script and in includes **REVOKE CONNECT**:

```
CREATE USER [MyUser]
    WITH PASSWORD = N'c2Aaaaaaaaaaaa';


GO
REVOKE CONNECT TO [MyUser];
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datareader', @membername = N'MyUser;
EXECUTE sp_addrolemember @rolename = N'db_datawriter', @membername = N'MyUser';
```

How to prevent the REVOKE CONNECT line being generated

Comment: Make sure the DAC package source doesn't contain the line.